# If $f(x)=2x-5$, when $f(x)=13$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $ \ f(x) = 2x - 5 \ $ , find $ \ x \ $ when $ \ f(x) = 13 \ $. I substituted 13 and got 21, but the answer was 9?

Can someone please show me working out for this type of question I'm bad at math!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $f(x)=13$. This means that:
$$f(x)=13=2x-5$$
$$\implies 13=2x-5$$
Now all we need to do is to solve this equation. First add $5$ to both sides.
$$13+5=2x$$
$$18=2x$$
Now divide by $2$ on both sides.
$$\frac{18}2=x$$
$$9=x$$
That is why $x=9$, as you said above.

---

If you want a more deeper understanding of what this problem is asking you to do, read on.

Say I have the function $f(x)=2x-1$, and I want to find $x$ when $f(x)=1$. This is like the reverse of plugging in an $x$ value into the function. We want to find what $x$ value we have to plug in.

What I will do now is find the *inverse* of $f(x)$. The inverse of any function $f(x)$ (denoted as $f^{-1}(x)$) must follow this rule (provided domain is correct):
$$f^{-1}(f(x))=x$$
This may seem very confusing to you. What this means is that the inverse function $f^{-1}(x)$ must have an $x$ value of $f(x)$. You will understand later.

How do you find inverses of functions? First, you substitute $y$ for $f(x)$.
$$y=2x-1$$
Then you switch $x$ and $y$.
$$x=2y-1$$
Now you have to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$.
$$x+1=2y$$
$$y=\frac{x+1}2$$
Lastly, substitute $f^{-1}(x)$ for $y$.
$$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x+1}2$$
That is the inverse of $f(x)$. Now I will show you what I mean by $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$. We evaluate $f(x)$ first, then plug in the value of $f(x)$ to $f^{-1}(x)$. Let's plug in an $x$ value of $3$. First, let's find $f(3)$.
$$f(3)=2(3)-1=6-1=5$$
Now we plug in $5$ as our $x$ value in $f^{-1}(x)$.
$$f^{-1}(5)=\frac{5+1}2=\frac 62=3$$
That means $f^{-1}(f(3))=3$, just as the rule says. This is a good way to check if your inverse is correct.

Since $f^{-1}(x)$ is the opposite of $f(x)$, then that means if $f(x)=y$, then $f^{-1}(y)=x$. This means that $f^{-1}(1)$ equals the $x$ value we have been trying to find.
$$f^{-1}(1)=\frac{1+1}2=\frac 22=1$$
Therefore our $x$ value is $1$. Let's see if this is correct.
$$f(1)=2(1)-1=2-1=1 \ \ \checkmark$$
You can use this way to find $x$ in your problem if you want. But the way I showed you at the top of the answer is IMHO the best way, because it is quicker.

Hope I helped

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = 2x-5$$

If $f(x)=13$, then that means you want to find an $x$, so that when you plug it into $f(x)$, you get 13.

$$f(x) = 13\\2x-5=13\\2x=18\\x=9$$

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to find $f(13)$ which is what you're doing by substituting $13$ for $x$ (and why you're getting $21$).  You want $x$ such that $f(x) = 13$ which means $2x-5 = 13$.  Can you take it from here?